# Postgres: distinct aggregation within group by

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, rdbms

I have an `events` table with 3 columns:

- sequence_id (the "offer" shown to many different cart sessions)
- checkout_token (the cart session for a single visitor)
- action (the type of event generated by the user with that cart session token)

I want to output data in the following (NOT real numbers according to my image, just dummy example of output format):

```
sequence_id      action_0_unique_count    action_1_unique_count
1                5                        4
2                2                        0
```

**im trying to count the DISTINCT number of event types (`action` enum column) PER checkout session, grouped by sequence_id**

[image]

Here's an image example of which rows I'm trying to select for column 2. Column 3 would be similar, except `WHERE action = 1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select sequence_id,
       count(distinct checkout_token) filter (where action = 0),
       count(distinct checkout_token) filter (where action = 1)
from events
group by sequence_id;
```

Comment: Thanks so much, always there is a simple answer that just... eludes me